# ODBC Connection to Microsoft Azure SQL "The server does not support SSL"

Tags: odbc, cloud, azure-sql-database, datastage

I am trying to establish a connection to a Microsoft Azure SQL database using an ODBC connection (`IBM Datastage v11.5`) but I get the following error:

> Connection failed
>   ODBC function "SQLConnect" reported: SQLSTATE=HY000: Native Error Code=0; Msg=[IBM(DataDirect OEM)][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver]The server does not support SSL

Here is my ODBC configuration file:

```
INI
Driver=/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/branded_odbc/lib/VMsqls00.so
Description=DataDirect SQL Server Native Wire Protocol
AlternateServers=
AlwaysReportTriggerResults=0
AnsiNPW=1
ApplicationName=
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
AuthenticationMethod=1
BulkBinaryThreshold=32
BulkCharacterThreshold=-1
BulkLoadBatchSize=1024
BulkLoadOptions=2
ConnectionReset=0
ConnectionRetryCount=0
ConnectionRetryDelay=3
CipherList=DEFAULT:!RC4
Database=DIFFCAISSE1
EnableBulkLoad=0
EnableQuotedIdentifiers=0
EncryptionMethod=1
FailoverGranularity=0
FailoverMode=0
FailoverPreconnect=0
FetchTSWTZasTimestamp=0
FetchTWFSasTime=1
GSSClient=native
HostName=myhostname.example.com
HostNameInCertificate=
InitializationString=
Language=
LoadBalanceTimeout=0
LoadBalancing=0
LoginTimeout=15
LogonID=
MaxPoolSize=100
MinPoolSize=0
PacketSize=-1
Password=
Pooling=0
PortNumber=1433
QueryTimeout=0
ReportCodePageConversionErrors=0
SnapshotSerializable=0
TrustStore=
TrustStorePassword=
ValidateServerCertificate=1
WorkStationID=
XML Describe Type=-10
```

Why is the driver complaining that the server does not support SSL?

Comment: HostName=myhostname.example.com  is that a valid url?

Comment: You sure azure sql and that odbc driver support the same protocol versions?

Comment: @JimVanPetten : No i changed it for the example but in my ini file there is a valid url

Comment: @Will wouldnt the error message mention it if there was a mismatch ? it that a know behavior for that case ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak ODBC.  That would be one of the things I did verify, tho.

Comment: is it https:// ?  and can you navigate there with a browser, ie do they have an ssl cert?